# Coprime sum triplets

Tags: number-theory, coprime

a+b+c=20

If a,b,c are coprime natural numbers  to each other find number of triplets (a,b,c) ?

Apart from manual counting what formula can we derive for such problem ?

Comment: Only counting cases manually